# Convert basic array to PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that I pull that looks like this:

`[157966745,275000353,43192565,305328212]`...

How do I go about taking that "string" and converting it to a PHP array which I can then manipulate.

Comment: You have an array which you want to convert to... an array also?

Comment: PHP doesn't accept that format as an array, so yes.

Comment: Where does this come from? Is it really a string? If so, you should rename your question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This looks like [*JSON*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Json), so you can use [**`json_decode`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
$str = "[157966745,275000353,43192565,305328212]";
$data = json_decode($str);
```

Comment: Ahhh, you took the easy road. ;) +1

Comment: Works great. Should have realized it could be interpreted as JSON.  Thanks

Comment: @Switz: You're welcome. Note that this will only work if you have numeric values. Strings values would have to be enclosed in double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

With exact that code...

```
$string='[157966745,275000353,43192565,305328212]';
$newString=str_replace(array('[', ']'), '', $string); // remove the brackets
$createArray=explode(',', $newString); // explode the commas to create an array

print_r($createArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$s = "[157966745,275000353,43192565,305328212]";

$matches;
preg_match_all("/\d+/", $s, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP explode is built just for this.

`$result = explode(',', $input)`

Comment: What about the square brackets?

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('/([\[|\]])/','',$strarr);
$new_arr=explode(','$strarr);
```